# Is this push pull amplifier wrong?

Tags: push-pull

Under the following tutorial:

http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/biasing-techniques-bjt/

They explain push pull operation. But should't negative terminal be separate with the ground? Dont we need +Vcc and -Vcc

Here is the push-pull from the tutorial:

[image: http://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/03126.png]

EDIT: here is my simulation:

[image]

Green is input, red is output.

Comment: One of your transistors is upside down. And there's no base bias network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But should't negative terminal be separate with the ground? Dont we
>   need +Vcc and -Vcc

No, that would work providing the load is connected via an output coupling capacitor: -

[image]

Here's another: -

[image]

Comment: ? Because I simulated without a cap and the result was a rectified sinusoid

Comment: Yeah that might happen!

Comment: i edited my question. adding a cap didnt work for me. please see my schematics. just a cap is not enough?

Comment: oh is that because mine is not biased??

Comment: Q2 is the wrong way round too. Yes, the transistors need decent biasing.

Comment: oh i both didnt bias and put Q2 wrong way. :(( thanks

Comment: So the transistor Q3 is providing a current sink for the diodes to stabilise the voltage drop across them?

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't seem to have any (noticeable) DC offset so you can leave out the output capacitor for simulation sake.

You don't get a negative swing because the output is clipped between 0 and +Vcc. You can do one of two things to fix this:

1. Add a DC offset to your input signal and add output capacitor.
2. Add a negative supply equal to -(+Vcc).

Also, you would want to add a Vbias between the output stage inputs equal to 2*Vbe to keep both transistors at the verge of saturation.